# what does "malloc_trim(0)" really mean?

Tags: malloc, glibc, trim, sbrk

The [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_trim.3.html) told me so much and through it I know lots of the background knowledge of memory management of "glibc".

But I still get confused. does "**malloc_trim(0)**"(note zero as the parameter) mean (*1.*)all the memory in the "heap" section will be returned to OS ? Or (*2.*)just all "unused" memory of the top most region of the heap will be returned to OS ?

If the answer is (*1.*), what if the still used memory in the heap? if the heap has used momery at places somewhere, will them be eliminated, or the function wouldn't execute successfully?

While if the answer is (*2.*), what about those "**holes**" at places rather than top in the heap？　they're unused memory anymore, but the top most region of the heap is still used, will this calling work efficiently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

Man page of `malloc_trim` was committed here: https://github.com/mkerrisk/man-pages/blob/master/man3/malloc_trim.3 and as I understand, it was written by man-pages project maintainer, kerrisk in 2012 from scratch: https://github.com/mkerrisk/man-pages/commit/a15b0e60b297e29c825b7417582a33e6ca26bf65

As I can [grep the glibc's git, there are no man pages in the glibc](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git&a=search&h=HEAD&st=grep&s=malloc_trim), and no commit to malloc_trim manpage to document this patch. The best and the only documentation of glibc malloc is its source code: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c
There are `malloc_trim` comments from `malloc/malloc.c`:

```
Additional functions:
 malloc_trim(size_t pad);
 609 /*
 610   malloc_trim(size_t pad);
 611 
 612   If possible, gives memory back to the system (via negative
 613   arguments to sbrk) if there is unused memory at the `high' end of
 614   the malloc pool. You can call this after freeing large blocks of
 615   memory to potentially reduce the system-level memory requirements
 616   of a program. However, it cannot guarantee to reduce memory. Under
 617   some allocation patterns, some large free blocks of memory will be
 618   locked between two used chunks, so they cannot be given back to
 619   the system.
 620 
 621   The `pad' argument to malloc_trim represents the amount of free
 622   trailing space to leave untrimmed. If this argument is zero,
 623   only the minimum amount of memory to maintain internal data
 624   structures will be left (one page or less). Non-zero arguments
 625   can be supplied to maintain enough trailing space to service
 626   future expected allocations without having to re-obtain memory
 627   from the system.
 628 
 629   Malloc_trim returns 1 if it actually released any memory, else 0.
 630   On systems that do not support "negative sbrks", it will always
 631   return 0.
 632 */
 633 int      __malloc_trim(size_t);
 634
```

Freeing from the middle of the chunk **is not documented** as text in malloc/malloc.c and not documented in man-pages project. Man page from 2012 may be the first man page of the function, written not by authors of glibc. Info page of glibc only mentions M_TRIM_THRESHOLD of 128 KB:
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Malloc-Tunable-Parameters.html#Malloc-Tunable-Parameters  and don't list malloc_trim function https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Summary-of-Malloc.html#Summary-of-Malloc (and it also don't document memusage/memusagestat/libmemusage.so).

In december 2007 there was commit https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=68631c8eb92ff38d9da1ae34f6aa048539b199cc by Ulrich Drepper (it is part of glibc 2.9 and newer) which changed `mtrim` implementation (but it didn't change any documentation or man page as there are no man pages in glibc):

> - malloc/malloc.c (public_mTRIm): Iterate over all arenas and call
>
> mTRIm for all of them.
>   (mTRIm): Additionally iterate over all free blocks and use madvise
>   to free memory for all those blocks which contain at least one
>   memory page.

Unused parts of chunks (anywhere, including chunks in the middle), aligned on page size and having size more than page may be marked as `MADV_DONTNEED` https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blobdiff;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=c54c203cbf1f024e72493546221305b4fd5729b7;hp=1e716089a2b976d120c304ad75dd95c63737ad75;hb=68631c8eb92ff38d9da1ae34f6aa048539b199cc;hpb=52386be756e113f20502f181d780aecc38cbb66a

```
       INTERNAL_SIZE_T size = chunksize (p);

       if (size > psm1 + sizeof (struct malloc_chunk))
         {
           /* See whether the chunk contains at least one unused page.  */
           char *paligned_mem = (char *) (((uintptr_t) p
                                           + sizeof (struct malloc_chunk)
                                           + psm1) & ~psm1);

           assert ((char *) chunk2mem (p) + 4 * SIZE_SZ <= paligned_mem);
           assert ((char *) p + size > paligned_mem);

           /* This is the size we could potentially free.  */
           size -= paligned_mem - (char *) p;

           if (size > psm1)
               madvise (paligned_mem, size & ~psm1, MADV_DONTNEED);
        }
```

This is one of total two usages of `madvise` with `MADV_DONTNEED` in glibc now, one for top part of heaps (`shrink_heap`) and other is marking of any chunk (`mtrim`): http://code.metager.de/source/search?q=MADV_DONTNEED&path=%2Fgnu%2Fglibc%2Fmalloc%2F&project=gnu

```
 H A D  arena.c 643 __madvise ((char *) h + new_size, diff, MADV_DONTNEED);
 H A D  malloc.c    4535 __madvise (paligned_mem, size & ~psm1, MADV_DONTNEED);
```

We can test the `malloc_trim` with this simple C program (`test_malloc_trim.c`) and `strace`/`ltrace`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main()
{
    int *m1,*m2,*m3,*m4;
    printf("%s\n","Test started");
    m1=(int*)malloc(20000);
    m2=(int*)malloc(40000);
    m3=(int*)malloc(80000);
    m4=(int*)malloc(10000);
    // check that all arrays are allocated on the heap and not with mmap
    printf("1:%p 2:%p 3:%p 4:%p\n", m1, m2, m3, m4);
    // free 40000 bytes in the middle
    free(m2);
    // call trim (same result with 2000 or 2000000 argument)
    malloc_trim(0);
    // call some syscall to find this point in the strace output
    sleep(1);
    free(m1);
    free(m3);
    free(m4);
    // malloc_stats(); malloc_info(0, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

`gcc test_malloc_trim.c -o test_malloc_trim`, `strace ./test_malloc_trim`

```
write(1, "Test started\n", 13Test started
)          = 13
brk(0)                                  = 0xcca000
brk(0xcef000)                           = 0xcef000
write(1, "1:0xcca010 2:0xccee40 3:0xcd8a90"..., 441:0xcca010 2:0xccee40 3:0xcd8a90 4:0xcec320
) = 44
madvise(0xccf000, 36864, MADV_DONTNEED) = 0
...
nanosleep({1, 0}, 0x7ffffafbfff0)       = 0
brk(0xceb000)                           = 0xceb000
```

So, there was `madvise` with `MADV_DONTNEED` for 9 pages after `malloc_trim(0)` call, when there was hole of 40008 bytes in the middle of the heap.

Comment: Typical official position of GNU-like project maintainer on man pages and other documentation: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2531#c4 "Ulrich Drepper 2006-05-01 The man pages are not maintained in glibc.  Tell this to the man page maintainer."

Answer (score 7):

The man page for `malloc_trim` says it releases free memory, so if there is allocated memory in the heap, it won't release the whole heap.  The parameter is there if you know you're still going to need a certain amount of memory, so freeing more than that would cause glibc to have to do unnecessary work later.

As for holes, this is a standard problem with memory management and returning memory to the OS.  The primary low-level heap management available to the program is `brk` and `sbrk`, and all they can do is extend or shrink the heap area by changing the top.  So there's no way for them to return holes to the operating system; once the program has called `sbrk` to allocate more heap, that space can only be returned if the top of that space is free and can be handed back.

Note that there are other, more complex ways to allocate memory (with anonymous `mmap`, for example), which may have different constraints than `sbrk`-based allocation.

Comment: There is now method of returning holes in the middle of the heap back to OS: MADV_DONTNEED (and sometimes MADV_FREE): http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/malloc/malloc.c#4535 `mtrim (mstate av, size_t pad) ... __madvise (paligned_mem, size & ~psm1, MADV_DONTNEED);`. `madvise` with such flags marks pages as not needed for the application, OS may destroy data from them and unmap physical space; next access to page may generate pagefault to remap virtual page to physical space.

Comment: Code was added in https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=68631c8eb92ff38d9da1ae34f6aa048539b199cc 68631c8eb92ff38d9da1ae34f6aa048539b199cc "(mTRIm): Additionally iterate over all free blocks and use madvise to free memory for all those blocks which contain at least one memory page." -  Ulrich Drepper 16 Dec 2007 (glibc 2.9)